# Wait for messages in interaction Discord JS

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I want to make a function in Discord JS that waits for a message from the user and gets its content.

I tried to get message value in console but it returns "underfined"

*My example code:*

```
if (interaction.customId === ('voice_mute')) {
interaction.channel
    .send("Mention an user with `@`...")
    .then(() => {
        interaction.channel.awaitMessages({
            max: 1,
            time: 30000,
            errors: ['time'],
        })
        .then((message) => {
            message = message.first();
            if (message.content.startsWith("@")) {
                message.channel.send(`Correct`);
            }else {
                message.channel.send("Invalid");
            }
        })
        .catch((collected) => {
            interaction.channel.send('Timeout');
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: What intents have you enabled? Is `interaction` a slash command?

Comment: Also, if you mention someone, `message.content` will start with `<@`, not `@`.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you may have forgotten to enable the message content privileged intent.

Head over to  `https://discord.com/developers/applications > Your Application > Bot > Enable Message Content Intent` (Don’t forget to save!)

I’m unsure if this is applicable to your use case, but instead of relying on message content (which you will need to apply for if you get your bot verified), you should use the user interaction option in your command. You can do that like so:

```js
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('discord.js');

const data = new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName('hi')
    .setDescription('Say hi to someone')
    .addUserOption(option =>
        option.setName('Person')
            .setDescription('The person to say hi to'));
```

And then get the user as a user object like so:

```js
interaction.options.getUser(‘Person’)
```

Happy coding!